# Object loses css class on page leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a menu the folds out. When the user clicks a menu link and browser starts to load a new page the old page loses its body class `move-left`. Using inspector I can see that it clears the body class  before re-rendering the DOM. Can this behavior be prevented?

```
$( "#foo" ).click(function() {
  $( "body" ).toggleClass( "move-left" );
});
```

Where foo can be a menu button etc.

Comment: did you integrate the class ?

Comment: The JQuery script you are using removes it, try searching for it in the code and edit the code.